# Adding city names and geolocation data to dataframe

Tags: regex, r, geolocation, maps

I have a dataset with more than 20.000 observations that basically looks like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(
    user = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"),
    location = c("Chicago, the windy city", "Oxford University", "Paris")
)
```

I want to add three additional columns `city`, `long`, `lat` and fill these columns with the city name, and the geolocations (longitude and latitude).

Therefore I thought to use the `maps` package and its `world.cities` database:

```
library(maps)
data(world.cities)
```

Adding the city names and geolocation would not be difficult, if the city names in `location` would be displayed in the right way. However, most of them do have additional strings (e.g. "Chicago, the windy city").

How can I extract just the city names based on the `world.cities` database and write the real city name to the column `city` and the geolocations to `long` and `lat`?

Comment: Is the city-name always first in the strings in `location`?

Comment: You are aware that there are multiple cities with the same name right ? For example, "Paris" is a city in France *and* in Canada. How do you want the results to be presented ?

Comment: 1) No, the city is not always first in the string (e.g. "University College London"). 2) Yes, I am. But if users do not add the specific country, I would take the bigger city

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per mentioned by @Heroka in the comments, if the name of the city is always the first string in `location`, you could extract the first string using `stringi`, `left_join` the world.cities data, and filter for the largest population in the matches.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(city = stri_extract_first_words(location)) %>%
  left_join(world.cities, by = c("city" = "name")) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(row_number(desc(pop)) == 1)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
#Groups: city [3]
#
#    user                location    city country.etc     pop   lat   long capital
#  (fctr)                  (fctr)   (chr)       (chr)   (int) (dbl)  (dbl)   (int)
#1    ABC Chicago, the windy city Chicago         USA 2830144 41.84 -87.68       0
#2    DEF       Oxford University  Oxford          UK  157568 51.76  -1.26       0
#3    GHI                   Paris   Paris      France 2141839 48.86   2.34       1
```

---

**Update**

If the name of the city is not always the first string in `location`, you could first try to match the words in `location` with a dictionary (here the `name` column in world.cities) and then use the matches that return `TRUE` as your location name. Here's a quick implementation (I added the "University College London" case to you data.frame)

```
> df
#  user                  location
#1  ABC   Chicago, the windy city
#2  DEF         Oxford University
#3  GHI                     Paris
#4  JKL University College London
```

For each row, we extract all the words in `location` and store them in a list `lst`, loop over it to find the position of the matching `name` in world.cities  and store it in `p`, and finally extract the element corresponding to position `p` in `lst` and store it in `city`

```
df %>%
  mutate(lst = stri_extract_all_words(location),
         p = sapply(lst, function (x) which(x %in% world.cities$name), simplify=TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(city = sapply(1:length(lst), function(x) .$lst[[x]][.$p[x]])) %>%
  left_join(world.cities, by = c("city" = "name")) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(row_number(desc(pop)) == 1)
```

You can also remove the temporary columns `p` and `lst` by adding `... %>% select(-lst, -p)`

---

**Update 2**

This should not break on malformed words but won't work for the "New York" case:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    city = lapply(stri_extract_all_words(location), 
                  function (x) { world.cities$name[match(x, world.cities$name)] })) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(city) %>%
  filter(!is.na(city)) %>%
  left_join(world.cities, by = c("city" = "name")) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(row_number(desc(pop)) == 1)
```

---

**Update 3**

This should work in all the cases:

```
> df
#  user                  location
#1  ABC   Chicago, the windy city
#2  DEF         Oxford University
#3  GHI                     Paris
#4  JKL                  New York
#5  MNO                  m0ntr3al
#6  PQR University College London

df$l <- gsub("[^[:alnum:]]+", " ", df$location)
lst  <- lapply(world.cities$name, function (x) { grep(x, df$l, value = TRUE) })
m    <- data.table::melt(lst)

df %>% 
  left_join(m, by = c("l" = "value")) %>%
  left_join(world.cities %>% 
              add_rownames %>% 
              mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname)), 
            by = c("L1" = "rowname")) %>% 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(pop = 0)) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  filter(row_number(desc(pop)) == 1) %>%
  select(-(l:L1))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 8]
#Groups: location [6]
#
#    user                  location     name country.etc     pop   lat   long capital
#  (fctr)                    (fctr)    (chr)       (chr)   (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)   (int)
#1    ABC   Chicago, the windy city  Chicago         USA 2830144 41.84 -87.68       0
#2    DEF         Oxford University   Oxford          UK  157568 51.76  -1.26       0
#3    GHI                     Paris    Paris      France 2141839 48.86   2.34       1
#4    JKL                  New York New York         USA 8124427 40.67 -73.94       0
#5    MNO                  m0ntr3al       NA          NA       0    NA     NA      NA
#6    PQR Univeristy College London   London          UK 7489022 51.52  -0.10       1
```

Comment: Thank you! You brought me a big step further to my goal! I really appreciate that. I just have to figure out how to include the second part (lapply the city list) to the first script!

Comment: @feder80 Glad I could help. Have you figured out a way yet or would you need a suggestion ?

Comment: Thank you. The script works at first, however I encountered two problems: 1) if someone lives on "New York" (USA), the result is just "York" (UK). 2) if the name of a location is written wrong, the script stops with an error, instead of writing NA in city or something like that.

Comment: Hm, now the script changes Paris to Pari (Estonia) and Oxford University to U (Micronesia). :-(

Comment: @feder80 Have a look at `m`: `value` is the original `df$location` and `L1` is the row number of `world.cities` that correspond to the match(es) found. Here you have multiple matches but you filter them to keep only the one with the highest population.

Comment: I get the following warning: "In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector" But it seems to work. You are fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: I ran the script on my dataset and encountered to serious problems: 1) the script coerces my 20,000 observations to approximately 8,000 observations (and I do not know why). 2) the error rate is to high. :-(

Comment: I have thought about this problem. Wouldn't it be better to divide the solution in several steps, beginning with a search for cities with two names (New York, Los Angeles) and then a search in the remaining observations for cities with one name?

Comment: @feder80 At this point I would need your data (or a more representative subset / `dput()` of it) to explore other possibilities. Consider asking a new question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: that would be great, if you could have a look at the dataset. how can I send you the csv file? do you have an email?